# Is it possible to set my media keys to control ONLY the media player volume (not system volume)?

Tags: media-player, foobar2000, media-keys, logitech-keyboard

I have a Logitech G110 keyboard.

The volume scroller on my keyboard controls both my system volume and the volume of whatever media player is running at the time (currently Foobar).

Is it possible to disable system volume control and control only my media player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what media player you're using.  [Foobar](http://www.foobar2000.org/), for instance, allows you to [set global hotkeys](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Preferences:General:Keyboard_Shortcuts).  I have used this feature to set Function keys as volume controls, and this controls the media player's volume independently of the system volume on Windows.  However, that feature might not support your specialized keyboard volume scroller.

Comment: Yep, it depends on the media player in use. For what it's worth, WinAMP also supports this behavior. A more general approach might be possible by looking into the latest [Logitech Gaming Software](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/gaming-keyboard-g110?crid=404&osid=14&bit=32) which allows customizing of functions on the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks! The media player in question is actually Foobar (which I should've mentioned), and I've just set up some global hotkeys for volume control. My system volume is no longer being controlled, and Foobar is!